# Error making my first Texworks document

Tags: errors

I was trying to make my first document using Texworks but in the moment of saving I got this error message:

```
C:/Users/NicolÃ² Ruggeri/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.
log4cxx: setFile(C:\Users\Nicolò Ruggeri\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log/miktex-pdftex.log,true) call failed.
log4cxx: IO Exception : status code = 720003
log4cxx: No output stream or file set for the appender named [RollingLogFile].

Sorry, but C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-pdftex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/NicolÃ² Ruggeri/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.
```

This is what I wrote,based on an online document:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Un articolo inutile}
\author{A. U. Tore}

\maketitle

\section{Un paragrafo}

Testo che mostra quanto si possa scrivere
 inutilmente.

\subsection{Un paragrafo di secondo livello}

Testo sempre più inutile, ma con léttere accentàte
 e riferimenti allo stranißimo posto chiamato Ööç.

Ci mettiàmo anche un secondo capoverso.

\end{document}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the miktex configuration (there are plenty of miktex users on site, someone will be able to help:-) But I can confirm that there is no error in your document it should produce an error-free 1 page document once you have TeX set up.

Comment: What is the content of the file `C:/Users/NicolÃ² Ruggeri/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log`?

Comment: Can you make sure your MikTeX system is up to date by running the Updater in both user and Admin mode?

Comment: I have no problem compiling this code with MiKTeX. Did you try compiling from the command line?

Comment: MikTex is up to date (I downloaded it today) and the file was created by the programme itself (I didn't even have a NicolA Ruggeri folder before) but,even if I delete it,it still gives me the same errror. Where's the command line? I also tried the official lines of the help guide and they don't work then,as you confirm.there's no error in the code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and fought it for a while. Just got it working!

I believe it behaves the same way as Arduino does with special characters in user name. For me it tries to use AppData under two separate directories.

C:\Users\Filip GranÃ¶\AppData and C:\Users\Filip Granö\AppData

When initexmf.exe --quiet --update-fndb tries to update font database it fails and therefore pdflatex fails.

Here's what I did:

1. closed anything related to miktex
2. opened TeXworks as administrator
3. tried to run a typeset -> failed
4. closed TeXworks
5. deleted C:\Users\Filip GranÃ¶\AppData (created when ran as administrator)
6. opened cmd as administrator
7. created a symbolic link: C:\Users\Filip GranÃ¶>mklink /D AppData "..\Filip Granö\AppData"
8. opened cmd as myself
9. ran: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64>initexmf.exe --update-fndb  (no output == good)
10. tried to run a typeset -> asks to install packages needed
11. Install needed packages for user only! - you can set it to do it automatically

Result: it now works for me!